# rails: how to fix or erase a serialized field column that has legacy data of wrong type

Tags: ruby-on-rails, serialization

Our app has a text field :schedule.

Originally, we stored data as a string.

The we changed the model to `serialize :schedule, Hash`

To fix legacy data, we simply want to replace the old (string) data with nil.

However, once we added serialization, attempting to write anything (a nil, or a replacement hash) to the field (if it has a string) throws the exception:

```
ActiveRecord::SerializationTypeMismatch: schedule was supposed to be a Hash, but was a String
```

Is there any way to override the serialization exception and force the field to a nil, or a replacement hash?

Perhaps there's a way to bypass the serialization by doing an update to a field via SQL?

(I know we could use migrations to drop the column then re-add it, but am looking for a way to do this in a rake task.)

Comment: Do you eval the input before saving it? something like (but very dangerous!): `params[:schedule] = eval(params[:schedule]) || {}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [`update_column`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-update_column) to quickly update all records in your database. This will send a simple `UPDATE table SET schedule = NULL` to your database without respecting any validations or callbacks. Of course you'll loose all your data in this column, but as far as I understand your description that's not a problem, right?

Comment: unfortunately that only works on rails 3.1++ and this app is 3.0.17

Comment: You can run arbitrary SQL queries using `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute 'UPDATE table SET schedule = NULL'` alternatively